# Interactive animated characters running on this website. How to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

I am looking for ideas and inspiration on how to ca

http://hellpizza.com/nz/

trick as in the website below.

At the bottom of the page, there are a number of characters running around that can be interacted with.

What is the correct technology for achieving this? It appears to use JQuery, but i am unsure what modules it is using or where it's source variables are coming from.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: right click tells you all you need to know in these cases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website is using flash.

You could (and *should* IMHO) do it in javascript. There are many ways to achieve this, for exemple creating HTML elements containing sprites of the characters, or if your visitors use recent browsers use [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial).

Comment: Or HTML5... as long as we are doing shoulds

Answer (score 0):

The part of the page you're talking about is done completely in flash, here is the direct link to the swf I'm assuming you're talking about http://hellpizza.com/shared/flash/devils.swf

Answer (score 0):

It is done in Flash. Most likely with an array of animations, and a second animation shown with mouse over of the target area, the character.

There is no way, to my knowledge to see the code, but it looks pretty simple / straightforward.

Comment: You can easily view the code using something like Sothink's SWF Decompiler.

Comment: @RyanKempt Good to know, the last time I cared about Flash for anything I did, it was still Macromedia Flash...